# Horizontal scroll in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been trying to implement horizontal scroll in ionic 2 page. But the content always gets vertically scrolled.

I tried writing my own css by setting 'overflow-x to scroll'. But it didn't work. I also tried ionic's **ion-scroll** component by setting  'scrollX= true'. But the entire content got hidden. i.e it was not visible on the page at all. Below is the sample code i used for ion-scroll. Not sure what exactly i am missing here.

Any guidance on this pls?. (I am new to Ionic 2 and CSS. So sorry if the question is too simple.)

```
<ion-navbar *navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
        Title
    </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content>
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true">

        <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
                content
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
        <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
                content
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>

    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I achieved the horizontal scroll with several ionic components:

**ion-avatar scrollable HTML**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-row>
    <ion-item no-lines>
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true" scroll-avatar>
        <ion-avatar>
          <img src="../../assets/whatever.png" *ngFor="let avatar of avatars" class="scroll-item"/>
        </ion-avatar>
    </ion-scroll>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

**ion-icon scrollable HTML**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-scroll scrollX="true">
        <ion-icon *ngFor="let avatar of avatars" name="radio-button-on" class="scroll-item selectable-icon"></ion-icon>
      </ion-scroll>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

**SCSS**

```
  ion-scroll[scrollX] {
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;

    .scroll-item {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .selectable-icon{
      margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
      color: red;
      font-size: 100px;
    }

    ion-avatar img{
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }

  ion-scroll[scroll-avatar]{
    height: 60px;
  }

  /* Hide ion-content scrollbar */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display:none;
  }
```

That worked for me with ionic 3.2.0 version.

[ionic scrollX example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L7BH.png)

Comment: Works like a charm, It won't work in the browser, but it is working perfectly in ionic view app.

Answer (score 14):

None of the answers here worked for me. What I ended up with is the following HTML.

```
<ion-scroll scrollX style="height:200px;">
  <div class="scroll-item">
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-item">
    Item 2
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Along with this SCSS. It's important that the child elements are `display: inline-block`.

```
ion-scroll[scrollX] {
  white-space: nowrap;
  .scroll-item {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. Simple code but saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the **height** of your `<ion-scroll>` container. If you don't do this, it seems that the `<ion-scroll>` element always has a height of 0.

**Example:**

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="width:100vw;height:350px">
    <img src="test.jpg style="border:1px dotted red;width:700px;height:350px">
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: This was they key for me. Chrome and IE11 don't have this behavior but Safari certainly does.

Answer (score 3):

For horizontal scroll you need to add the following tag :

```
<scroll-content>
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true" class="item">
        //your content
    </ion-scroll>
</scroll-content>`
```

Your content should be within it.

This code worked for me:

```
<scroll-content >
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true"  class="item">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col>  
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
            <ion-col width-25>
                Item 1 
            </ion-col> 
        </ion-row>
    </ion-scroll>
</scroll-content>`
```

Comment: What is scroll content ?

Comment: width-25 is not supported by ionic 3, use col-{index}, index from 1 to 12.

Comment: scroll-content is not known element.

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 2 RC this code worked for me, i wanted to scroll a list of icons:

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="height: 50px;" >
  <ion-icon *ngFor="let icon of icons; let i = index" name={{icon.icon_name}} (click)="selectIcon(icon, i)"></ion-icon>
 </ion-scroll>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: `<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
  <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [page]="page" [original-size]="false" style="display: block;" [zoom]="zoom" [show-all]="false" [after-load-complete]="pdfDidLoad" [render-text]="true"></pdf-viewer></ion-scroll>` and scss is:`pdf-viewer{

overflow: scroll;
// background-attachment:scroll;

}



 
 ion-scroll 
 { 
  white-space: nowrap; 
  height: 100%;
 }
`   its not working sir where i am going wrong

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this issue too. I solve it like this:

**1. Add this property to you `<ion-scroll>` tag in your .html file:**

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
... your content ...
</ion-scroll>`
```

**2. Add this to you .scss file:**

```
ion-scroll{
  overflow: scroll; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

That should work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the exact issue you are having, but if your in a view which has swipe back enabled it will prevent horizontal scrolling anywhere on that page. Here's how to turn it off inside the @Page class:

```
constructor(nav: NavController) {
   nav.swipeBackEnabled = false;
}
```