# Horizontal scrolling of Table in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, horizontal-scrolling

I have a dynamic generated Table that I want to show in a Ionic 2 Page.
The problem is that when the table is wider than the screen the table just gets cut what makes it impossible to read it entirely.

So a horizontal scroll would solve this problem and I already found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959258/horizontal-scroll-in-ionic-2) but the answer of that question does not work with tables. Has anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by wrapping the table with a div and adding "overflow-x:auto" to the div.

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table></table>
</div>
```