# horizontal scrollable cards ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am new to mobile web development. I'm using Ionic2 as my framework. In my app I want to present the users with a horizontal scrollable view of cards. This is quite common in apps in the market like Google Play, Redbox etc.

Any pointers or help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Use the `ion-slides` component and in each slide use an `ion-card` component  http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#slides

Comment: I've solved this issue using scrollX="true" and <https://stackoverflow.com/a/44216689/7123058>

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/reWVod) from the official ionic team. The relevant keywords are `scrollX=true` in the  `ion-scroll`, and

```
ion-scroll { white-space: nowrap; 
height: 150px }
```

For the `ion-scroll` css.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if i embed this image into ion-card. 

`<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
    <ion-card *ngFor="#item of newMovieItems">
      <ion-item>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-scroll>`

Answer (score 0):

The ion-card is by default a `block` element. So a CSS rule to make it an `inline-block` element instead does the trick. And giving it a width also;

HTML

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true"> 
       <ion-card *ngFor="#item of items"> 
           <ion-item>
             <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> 
           </ion-item>
        </ion-card> 
    </ion-scroll>
```

CSS

```
ion-scroll {
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 150px
}

img{
  margin: 10px;
}

ion-card{
  width: 30vw;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This is a plunker: http://codepen.io/RaymondAtivie/pen/ZORvzd